# How to create an immutable list in Python?

Tags: python, list, variables

I'm facing some problems with variables in my program. I need to keep two or three versions of a list that changes during loop evaluation. For example:

```
x=[0]  
y=[0]  
while True:
        y=x  
        x[0]+=1  
        print (y,x)    
        input()
```

As I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it shows `[1] [1]; [2] [2]; [3] [3]...` But I need to keep the previous state of the list in a variable: `[0] [1]; [1] [2]; [2] [3] ...`

What should the code be?

Comment: @Idos That answers the title, but not really the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to copy the value instead of the reference, you can do:

```
y=x[:]
```

Instead

```
y = x
```

You also can use the copy lib:

```
import copy
new_list = copy.copy(old_list)
```

If the list contains objects and you want to copy them as well, use generic copy.deepcopy()

```
new_list = copy.deepcopy(old_list)
```

In python 3.x you can do:

```
newlist = old_list.copy()
```

You can do it in the ugly mode as well :)

```
new_list = list(''.join(my_list))
```

Comment: In my particular case in a real program with nested lists, only deepcopy() made a difference. Like: y = deepcopy(x).

Answer (score 6):

Actually you don't need an immutable list. What you really need is creating real **copy** of list instead of just copying references. So I think the answer to your issue is:

```
y = list(x)
```

Instead of `y = x`.